# Simplify expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, vector, list-manipulation

Suppose I have expressions that involve terms like:

```
p1.p1+p2.p2+p3.p3+p4.p4
```

p1, p2, p3, and p4 are all elements of an array:

```
p={p1, p2, p3, p4}
```

I would like Mathematica to replace this term with simply "p^2" anytime it sees it. How do I tell it to do this?

Comment: So p1 ... p4 are all scalars? Why do you have an expression involving them in a dot product then? That seems an issue in and of itself... Have you tried `{p1, p2, p3, p4}.{p1, p2, p3, p4}` instead? That is equivalent to `p.p` with your definition of `p`, and it returns `p1^2 + p2^2 + p3^2 + p4^2`, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Define p as a vector: then the symbol p represents the vector {p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]], p[[4]]}. Or define p as a function with designated values p[1], p[2], p[3] and p[4].